# A misconception of "embroiled", and what word(s) should be used for what I **thought** it meant?

Tags: adjectives

Here's a sentence I just wrote:

> The Chief was embroiled with passion in his work.

Luckily I immediately looked up the word. To my dismay, I had a completely wrong understanding of the word "embroiled". I thought it was a fancy word for something like **"suddenly filled with something that was generated internally"**.

I looked up synonyms for "filled" but didn't find anything that matched that definition I want. Is there any single word or small phrase that denotes what I'm looking for? Something that just now was filled or filling into a person (the Chief). That's the adjectival definition I want.

I believe I got my misconception of "embroiled" from the words "embodied" and/or "imbued". I don't know where I got the "just now" or "suddenly" part from, but that's part of the meaning I want too.

Comment: generated internally? Care to reword?

Comment: If you substitute your embroiled for **overcome**, then I suppose that would help give the emphasis you want

Comment: I was going to suggest you might have been thinking of _imbued_ but that would properly suggest an external source.

Comment: @NeilW Well maybe, but maybe you can imbue yourself with something? I edited the OP with more info.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the word **infused** as it implies a state of being filled, so sounds like it has a meaning that is close to what you intended.

According to the [Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/infuse), the word has the following meaning (point two seems to be the one intended):

> infuse (ɪnˈfjuːz)
>
> verb
>
> 1. (often foll by: into) to instil or inculcate
> 2. (foll by: with) to inspire; emotionally charge
> 3. to soak or be soaked in order to extract flavour or other properties
> 4. (foll by into) to pour

Answer (score 0):

> *The Chief was passionate about his work*

That's how you communicate that generally. Which is not to say that there aren't a whole host of words that could fit into your sentence; we just don't know what you're trying to say.

For instance, you could say:

> The chief **burned** with passion for his work"

That has a sort of righteous feel to it. Maybe even quasi religious, depending on your reader.

> The chief was **consumed** with passion for his work

That one says something borderline negative. Maybe that passion is harming him somehow. In any case, we get the impression that there isn't room for anything else in his life.

> The chief **glowed** with passion for his work.

That one fees really pure, and happy, and very immediate. It feels like you're looking at him right now, not describing him in general.

There are plenty more, and all of them come with similar connotations. If you go down this path, choose wisely.

Comment: Not bad but i need to clarify that the chief just now became impassioned. It happened just now or just a few moments ago. Maybe we could add "suddenly". The Chief suddenly glowed with passion. I will edit the OP.